# Iterating over $_POST produce unexpected results

Tags: php, arrays

I'm giving an array to this function.

```
function updateColors($mysqli, $variables){

var_dump($variables);

foreach($variables as $key=>$value) {



    if (is_int($key) && $value){
        error_log("changing: " . $key . " to " .  $value);

        $mysqli->select_db("hotel");

        $sql = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE `statuses`
        SET  `color` =  ?
        WHERE  `ID` =  ?;
        ");

        $sql->bind_param('si', $value, $key);

        if($sql->execute())
            return("Colors updated.");
        else
            return("Unexpected error while updating colors.");

    } else 
    error_log("NOT changing: " . $key . " to " .  $value);

}

}
```

Here's the result of the `var_dump`

```
array(11) { 
["statcolor0"]=> string(6) "000000" 
[0]=> string(12) "rgb(0, 0, 0)"
["statcolor1"]=> string(6) "000000"
[1]=> string(12) "rgb(0, 0, 0)"
["statcolor2"]=> string(6) "000000"
[2]=> string(12) "rgb(0, 0, 0)"
["statcolor3"]=> string(6) "000000"
[3]=> string(12) "rgb(0, 0, 0)"
["statcolor4"]=> string(6) "000000"
[4]=> string(12) "rgb(0, 0, 0)"

["UpdateColors"]=> string(13) "Update Colors" }
```

However, it looks like my foreach loop doesn't iterate correctly through all the values in the array. This is the result of the `error_log`

```
[15-Apr-2013 15:08:37] NOT changing: statcolor0 to 000000
[15-Apr-2013 15:08:37] changing: 0 to rgb(0, 0, 0)
```

And nothing else! Quite strangely, most of the items in the array are missing and not logged in the error log. Why is that?

Comment: `is_int($key)` is it your intent to check that "statcolor0" is an int? Or only caring about the numeric keys? (seems like a poor way to check deltas)

Comment: as you can see, there are also numeric keys in the array. I want to filter out those and operate only on these...

Comment: You probably want to break out the `is_int` check? i.e. `if (is_int($key)) { if ($value !== false) {} else {} } else {}`, no?

Comment: why would I want to do that? I want to check if the value is int AND also if there is a value. Because of a poorly written client-side code it could be that some of the values are empty.

Comment: btw, the "return" breaks the loop! I've just figured that out... I hate when I post questions and figure out the solution just a few seconds later. I've been searching for the bug since ours!

Comment: Well, checking `if ($value)` when it's black (`000000`) is probably resulting in a falsy expression. You should be checking `empty($value)` or be putting it through some hex/color name validator.

Comment: Don't worry, $values will always be either empty or have an rgb statement like rgb(something, something, something)... So, in the case of white it would be "rgb(0,0,0)"... Is a hassle to have rgb on the server-side and hex on the client side. Nice spot btw :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28260/discussion-between-saturnix-and-brad-christie)